# Should I host support forum on wordpress.org or my own website?

Tags: plugins, support

I have a Wordpress plugin WP Pipes hosted at http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pipes/.

I see that it is convenience for users to ask question right in the support page at http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/wp-pipes, but it will be a pain when we have lots of topics in there.

Is there anyone here have experience about that? Should we offer support service right there in wordpress.org or host it in our own website?

Any help would be appreciate.

PS: I posted this question on stackoverflow but not has much answers for it.

Comment: Interesting question. Technically this is opinion-based and off-topic, but I'd be interested to hear other's opinions. Personally, all of my support forums are hosted at wordpress.org, but I don't handle a ton of support threads.

Comment: Yes, I would love to hear cons and pros for both options OR even the third option :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All my support forums are on WordPress.org, but I do all my development on GitHub and that has led to a few support issues filtering in to the issues stream that are support issues and not bug reports. I also got a handful of people commenting on my blog for support, but I closed all the plugin-related blog posts. I disagree that a forum is necessarily better. I love digging through forums, but most users won't.

I don't see why email is not manageable. In fact, some companies are using services like zendesk to handle support completely via email.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to keep all of my support threads in a centered location. It just seems easier to manage. With that being said I have a support area where users can post issues on the GitHub page. Majority of my support goes up on the wp.org forum in the plugin repo. The smallest amount of support comes via email.

Comment: Thank for the answer, but I don't think we have enough eyes to look at the all separate places from wp.org, github and email.

Comment: Well, I link all of mine to one central email - something like support@evansplugins.com or something. So any new issue that arises either on github or the wp.org repo, I get an email alerting me. I can then follow up with each support question. It's really just me maintaining the plugins and offering support, and I'm able to keep watch on multiple locations without much issue.

Comment: Actually, I have many guys are working with me in my company and I'm not a fan of email, it is kinda non-manageable. A forum is much more better.
I would love to hear your opinion about pros & cons when hosting your forum on wp.org or your own website, it would be very helpful.